# OxyPlot. How to change Format of values next to the axis from 1000 to 1k

Tags: c#, string-formatting, oxyplot

Im trying to change the format of the value next to the axis from for example 1000 to 1k or 1000000 to 1M.

Is this possible in LinearAxis?

This is my Code:

```
            m.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Right,
            IsZoomEnabled = false,
            IsPanEnabled = false,
            Minimum = -(_maxPointValue2*0.1),
            Maximum = _maxPointValue2 + (_maxPointValue2*0.1),
            FontSize = 15,
            Key = "right",
            TickStyle = TickStyle.Outside,

        });
```

Is this perhaps possible with StringFormat?

Also is it possible to change the TickStyle, so that the dashes going trough the whole plot?

Thanks in advance

Michael

Answer (score 8):

You can use the LabelFormatter property of the Axis class to change from 1000 to 1K etc.

Create your formatting function to take a double and return a string:

```
private static string _formatter(double d)
    {
        if (d < 1E3)
        {
            return String.Format("{0}", d);
        }
        else if (d >= 1E3 && d < 1E6)
        {
            return String.Format("{0}K", d / 1E3);
        }
        else if (d >= 1E6 && d < 1E9)
        {
            return String.Format("{0}M", d / 1E6);
        }
        else if (d >= 1E9)
        {
            return String.Format("{0}B", d / 1E9);
        }
        else
        {
            return String.Format("{0}", d);
        }
    }
```

Then add it to the Axis class:

```
plotmodel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
        {
            //Other properties here
            LabelFormatter = _formatter,
        });
```

Comment: Is there a way you can change the interval at which the parameter increases by? I'm working on a similar issue, but I can't seem to adjust the interval correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I use this approach. Based on [Metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix). Works for values in interval `(-Inf, 0.001> u <1000, +Inf)` ie `0.001` convert to `1m`, `1000` to `1k` etc

```
// Axis
PlotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
{
    Title = "Value",
    LabelFormatter = ValueAxisLabelFormatter,
});

// ValueAxisLabelFormatter method
private string ValueAxisLabelFormatter(double input)
        {
            double res = double.NaN;
            string suffix = string.Empty;

            // Prevod malych hodnot
            if (Math.Abs(input) <= 0.001)
            {
                Dictionary<int, string> siLow = new Dictionary<int, string>
                {
                    [-12] = "p",
                    [-9] = "n",
                    [-6] = "μ",
                    [-3] = "m",
                    //[-2] = "c",
                    //[-1] = "d",
                };

                foreach (var v in siLow.Keys)
                {
                    if (input != 0 && Math.Abs(input) <= Math.Pow(10, v))
                    {
                        res = input * Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(v));
                        suffix = siLow[v];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Prevod velkych hodnot
            if (Math.Abs(input) >= 1000)
            {
                Dictionary<int, string> siHigh = new Dictionary<int, string>
                {
                    [12] = "T",
                    [9] = "G",
                    [6] = "M",
                    [3] = "k",
                    //[2] = "h",
                    //[1] = "da",
                };

                foreach (var v in siHigh.Keys)
                {
                    if (input != 0 && Math.Abs(input) >= Math.Pow(10, v))
                    {
                        res = input / Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(v));
                        suffix = siHigh[v];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return double.IsNaN(res) ? input.ToString() : $"{res}{suffix}";
        }
```