# Oxyplot doesn't show values of time axis

Tags: c#, plot, diagram, milliseconds, oxyplot

I want to plot data values on a time axis with milliseconds.
This is my approach:

```
myModel = new PlotModel();

myModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis());
myModel.Axes.Add(new DateTimeAxis()
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
    StringFormat = "HH:mm:ss",
    IntervalLength = 60,
    MinorIntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds,
    IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds,
    MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
    MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
});

var cs = new LineSeries();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) //generate test values
{
    var dp = new DataPoint()
    {
        X = DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(DateTime.ParseExact("14:02:02.0" + Convert.ToString(i + 9), "HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
        Y = i * i
    };
    cs.Points.Add(dp);
}

myModel.Series.Add(cs);
```

The problem is that the graph doesn't show the values on the x-axis:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0svlC.png)

If I don't parse the milliseconds, everything is shown correctly:

```
DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(DateTime.ParseExact("14:02:" + Convert.ToString(i + 9), "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

The time is parsed correctly, but Oxyplot somehow can't cope with it.

Answer (score 0):

First guess: when you change the date time parsing your values are suddenly in the millisecond range because of your for loop and the way you append on the time. e.g.

```
"14:02: + Convert.ToString(i+9)" gives you 14:02:10 through 14:02:18

"14:02:02.0 + Convert.ToString(i+9)" gives you 14:02:02.10 through 14:02:02.18
```

Given your format string for the DateTimeAxis

```
StringFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
```

It cant display the millisecond resolution so you see nothing. Change your string formatting (Or dont specify it) to:

```
StringFormat = "HH:mm:ss.fff"
```

OR specify a label formatter to selectively display at the millisecond resolution similar to this question: [OxyPlot. How to change Format of values next to the axis from 1000 to 1k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349725/oxyplot-how-to-change-format-of-values-next-to-the-axis-from-1000-to-1k)

Comment: Regarding http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9922180, don't do that. Instead, post your own answer please.